# Changing the font of item text using a macro prefix on \item

Tags: enumitem, grouping

#### MWE

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{menukeys}
\usepackage{enumitem}
\usepackage{xcolor}

\newcommand\alternate{\color{gray}}
\newcommand\alternatereset{\color{black}}
\newcommand\keyify[1]{\keys{\ttfamily#1}}
\newlist{keylist}{description}{1}
\setlist[keylist]{
  labelindent = 2ex,
  itemsep     = -1ex,
  font        = \alternatereset\keyify,
  before      = \ttfamily\let\&\alternate
}

\begin{document}
\begin{keylist}
  \item[C-M-x]   cider-eval-defun-at-point
\&\item[C-c C-c] cider-eval-defun-at-point
  \item[C-c C-f] cider-pprint-eval-defun-at-point
\end{keylist}
\end{document}
```

[image: output]

I'd like to have just the second `cider-eval-defun-at-point` be grayed out.  I've tried using `\aftergroup` before `\alternatereset` in `\font` to no avail – in fact, this negates the effect of `\&` (probably because the label is in a group).

Comment: changing the font of just a limited string of text requires a well defined scope, and `\item` doesn't have a defined scope.  (i'm sure you know that.)  i think the best you can do is define another alternate to reset the font at the beginning of the next item, but i'm not sure that this won't persist after the end of the list, and don't have time to experiment.

Comment: @barbarabeeton Even using `\xpretocmd{\item}{\alternatereset}{}{}` in the `before` key doesn't work – since `\&` is placed before `\item`, `\item` immediately undoes the work of `\&` in this case.

Comment: i was thinking of something like changing the `before` line to something like `before      = \ttfamily\let\&\alternate \let\=\alternatereset` and putting `\=` before the next item.

Comment: @barbarabeeton Hmm, yeah that would work. But it looses some of the semantic goodies. I found a workaround, though: `\def\alternate\item[#1]{\item[#1]\color{gray}}` – see my answer for a full explanation.

Answer (score 3):

We could prepend the reset to each `\item`.
This immediately raises a problem:

```
\&\item[foo] bar                          & input syntax
\color{gray}\item[foo] bar                & \& is expanded
\color{gray}\color{black}\item[foo] bar   & \item is 'expanded'
```

We're immediately resetting the color each time.
So how can we solve this?

We can define `\alternate` to gobble and re-insert the `\item` in the correct position:

```
\def\alternate\item[#1]{\item[#1]\color{gray}}
```

This turns our expansion into:

```
\&\item[foo] bar                          & input syntax
\item[foo]\color{gray} bar                & \& is expanded
\color{black}\item[foo]\color{gray} bar   & \item is 'expanded'
```

This gives us the correct sequence.

#### Full MWE

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{menukeys}
\usepackage{enumitem}
\usepackage{xcolor}
\usepackage{xpatch}

\def\alternate\item[#1]{\item[#1]\color{gray}}
\newcommand\alternatereset{\color{black}}
\newcommand\keyify[1]{\keys{\ttfamily#1}}
\newlist{keylist}{description}{1}
\setlist[keylist]{
  labelindent = 2ex,
  itemsep     = -1ex,
  font        = \keyify,
  before      = \let\&\alternate
                \xpretocmd{\item}{\alternatereset}{}{}
                \ttfamily
}

\begin{document}
\begin{keylist}
  \item[C-M-x]   cider-eval-defun-at-point
\&\item[C-c C-c] cider-eval-defun-at-point
  \item[C-c C-f] cider-pprint-eval-defun-at-point
\end{keylist}
\end{document}
```

[image: output]

Comment: The idea is good, but issuing `\color{gray}` in that way produces a whatsit in vertical mode, that can have consequences on spacing. Since `\item` exploits `\everypar`, you can do `\def\alternate\item[#1]{\item[#1]\everypar=\expandafter{\the\everypar\color{gray}}}`; you could add to `before` also `\colorlet{keylist}{.}` and do `\color{keylist}` in the definition of `\alternatereset`, so as to catch the current color.